# ERROR 1449 (HY000) exists even after correcting the definer in dump file

Tags: mysql

Initially I had a DEFINER='invaliduser'@'23.35.%.%' defined in mysql dump file. This user here was invalid and I loaded this dump file accidentally.

Later, after dropping that DB , replacing the user with the proper user I ran the script again on new DB. However, I still see the previous error. Any idea/suggestions please?

> ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 9897: The user specified as a definer ('invaliduser'@'12.25.%.%') does not exist

Comment: Computers don't make up things like this. If it says that appears on line 9897, it almost certainly does. You must have made a mistake when editing the file.

Comment: True that. I wish the issue this was as simple. I carefully edited the file and have verified atleast 10 times for now :(

Comment: Maybe you're loading the wrong version of the file. I've occasionally spent an hour trying to debug something, and it turned out that I was running the script from the wrong directory.

Comment: That was certainly possible. I very carefully checked it, NOT the case

Comment: I don't know how you expect us to tell what's going wrong. It has to be something in the dump file or the way you're loading it.

Comment: I obviously have cross checked human errors before posting this question. I expect suggestion more in mysql context, like is it anyway mysql is storing the session with DEFINER, which is obviously not getting overriden,